# PHP preg_replace performance

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have approximately 51000 lines of dictionaries. I replace it with matches in the written content. but very bad performance. The server does not respond for a very long time with a content of about 2000 characters.

```php
  $search = Lugat::all()->map(function ($query) {
       return '/(?i)'. $query->kelime . '/';
  })->toArray();

  $replace = Lugat::all()->map(function ($query) {
       return "<a href='#' id='lugat' data-html='true' class='text-info'  data-original-title='\\0' data-content='". str_replace(["'", '"'], ["’", "“"], $query->aciklama) ."'><u>\\0</u></a>";
  })->toArray();

  return preg_replace($search, $replace, $value);
```

Example

```php
$replace = [
    "<a href='#' id='lugat' data-html='true' class='text-info'  data-original-title='\\0' data-content='". str_replace(["'", '"'], ["’", "“"], $query->aciklama) ."'><u>\\0</u></a>",
    "<a href='#' id='lugat' data-html='true' class='text-info'  data-original-title='\\0' data-content='". str_replace(["'", '"'], ["’", "“"], $query->aciklama) ."'><u>\\0</u></a>",
    "<a href='#' id='lugat' data-html='true' class='text-info'  data-original-title='\\0' data-content='". str_replace(["'", '"'], ["’", "“"], $query->aciklama) ."'><u>\\0</u></a>",
    "<a href='#' id='lugat' data-html='true' class='text-info'  data-original-title='\\0' data-content='". str_replace(["'", '"'], ["’", "“"], $query->aciklama) ."'><u>\\0</u></a>",
    // 51.000 ROW
];

$search = [
    '/(?i)AL/',
    '/(?i)AK/',
    '/(?i)ALİ/',
    '/(?i)AS/',
    // 51.000 ROW
];

$content = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
```

I don't know how to send 51000 rows sample.

Comment: Which part is very long? Build of `$search`, build of `$replace` or `preg_replace`? Have you benchmarcked them? Could you show an example of `$value`, `$search` and `$replace` so we can make some tests?

Comment: Try converting it to a single regex search: `/(?i)($queryOne|$queryTwo|$queryThree)/` & a use a single replacement callback like: `return "<a ...data-content='".str_replace(.., $matches[0])` or something. & then you'd need to use `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: Also, make sure `pcre.jit` is enabled (set to `1`). https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.jit . On my shared host, the pcre JIT compiler is not available.

Comment: @Reed will do what he said and return the results. I'm using PHP8 by the way.